# The provided 'src' attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sanity

I am using Sanity image url in my project and I am getting this error in my console page that says

[img of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeZnR.png)

This error pops up when ever I use the testimonial component in the react app> I am trying to make a portfolio but do not know how to fix this. I have ImageUrlBuilder worked fine in other components but it's giving an error with this one.

```
const Testimonial = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [testimonials, setTestimonials] = useState([]);
  const [brands, setBrands] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "testimonials"]';
    const brandsQuery = '*[_type == "brands"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setTestimonials(data);
    });

    client.fetch(brandsQuery).then((data) => {
      setBrands(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {testimonials.length && (
        <>
          <div className="app__testimonial-item app__flex">
            <img src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl)} alt={testimonials[currentIndex].name} />
            <div className="app__testimonial-content">
              <p className="p-text">{testimonials[currentIndex].feedback}</p>
              <div>
                <h4 className="bold-text">{testimonials[currentIndex].name}</h4>
                <h5 className="p-text">{testimonials[currentIndex].company}</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="app__testimonial-btns app__flex">
            <div className="app__flex" onClick={() => handleClick(currentIndex === 0 ? testimonials.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1)}>
              <HiChevronLeft />
            </div>

            <div className="app__flex" onClick={() => handleClick(currentIndex === testimonials.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1)}>
              <HiChevronRight />
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      <div className="app__testimonial-brands app__flex">
        {brands.map((brand) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: 'tween' }}
            key={brand._id}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(brand.imgUrl)} alt={brand.name} />
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Testimonial, 'app__testimonial'),
  'testimonial',
  'app__primarybg',
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the [docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/image-url#usage)?

`urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl).url()`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem ;) . The course is from 2020 so some things changed over the time.

You are missing `.url()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There i has the same probléme i just changed this Line :

```
     <img
      src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgUrl).width(200)}
      alt="testimonial"
    />
```

to This line :

```
 <img
          src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl).width(200)}
          alt="testimonial"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the image is not read by your browser which is stored in Sanity. You can it's getting by browser or not through the console.
before the return, write this code to check testimonial is exist or not,

```js
console.log('test data', testimonials);
```

You can check all attributes' names (name, company, feedback, imageurl),

It might be you have to use the different attribute name instead '*imgurl*'.

So Try this code,

```js
src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imageurl)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a `console.log('test data', testimonials)` and then opened up the object.

I noticed that the correct spelling was `imageurl` and not `imgurl`. That solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

The response for this image is different
instead of typing

```
src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl)}
```

type this :

```
src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imageurl)}
```

Everything else is correct