# Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder

Tags: javascript, sanity

I am trying to connect backend data from Sanity to my frontend in React.

1. The following is my client.js file where I setup the Sanity client:

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

// Connect react app to the sanity client
export const client = createClient({
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: "production",
    apiVersion: "2023-04-24",
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

This works to generate the text content from the Sanity backend but runs into an issue when trying to obtain the images.

2. The following error is what I see:

```
Warning: The provided `src` attribute is an unsupported type ImageUrlBuilder. This value must be coerced to a string before before using it here.
    at img
    at div
    at MotionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62475:59)
    at div
    at About (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:695:78)
    at div
    at App
```

3. The following is the code the Sanity docs suggest:
   (Link to the configuration of Sanity client per the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sanity/client)

```
import React from 'react'
import myConfiguredSanityClient from './sanityClient'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(myConfiguredSanityClient)

function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516915/the-provided-src-attribute-is-an-unsupported-type-imageurlbuilder

Comment: @johnSmith Thank you for linking that! I had looked at it multiple times prior to posting my question but I think the late night had me reading my console errors wrong and I assumed that my problem was different and was coming from my client setup. However, a fresh pair of eyes today realized it was just very similar and I was just using imgURL instead of imgUrl in my React component.